# Потерялся комментарий

Tags: дефект, комментарии

Вот так отображаются комментарии под [ответом](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/995214/178988):

> [image: скриншот ответа с комментариями]

А на самом деле там вот так:

> [image: скриншот с удалёнными комментариями]

Почему в первом случае не отображается последний комментарий?

> Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95242/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-ant).

Comment: Написал ещё один комментарий и ваш появился. Думаю, какого-то рода кеш

Comment: Вот уж кэш тут точно не при чём. наверное... Тем более, комментарий показывался до удаления.

Comment: А рефреш страницы не помогал на тот момент? Скрыть/показать удалённые, наверное, не перезагружает же всю страницу. Может ещё, конечно, какой-то нюанс, что данное сообщение по сути генерится системой.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ 1. Нет, рефреш не помогал. 2. Открытие вприватном окне тоже не помогало - комментария не было. 3. Показ удалённых перезагружает только комментарии, но не страницу. 4. А вот скрыть удалённые без обновления страницы нельзя.